# Advantages of epoll integration

Tags: performance, go, epoll

On one job interview I had to answer this question - which advantages do you have owing to use epoll integration/implementation in Go.

I just know what can do epoll and that complexity for any descriptors count is O(1), but have no idea why Go is better than other languages.

I found this branch https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15624586 and guy say that reason, maybe, that Go don't use stack switching. It's hard to understand for me. Which part of program don't use stack switching? Every goroutine has his own stack.

Comment: That comment was referring to a single-thread use case, in which case there is no stack switching because there is only a single goroutine (nothing to switch between).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the netpoller integration *per se* which makes Go strong in its field—it's rather the way that integration is done: instead of being bolted-on as a library, in Go, the netpoller is tightly integrated right into the runtime and the scheduler (which decides which goroutine to run, and when).

The coupling of super-light-weight threads of execution—goroutines—with the netpoller allows for *callback-free* programming. That is, once your service gets another client connected, you just hand this connection to a goroutine which merely reads the data from it (and writes its response stream to it). As soon as there's no data available when the goroutine wants to read it, the scheduler suspends the goroutine and unblocks it once the netpoller reports there's data available; the same happens when the goroutine wants to write data but the sending buffer is full.

To recap, the netpoller in Go is intertwined with the goroutine scheduler which allows goroutines transparently wait for data availability without requiring the programmer to explicitly code the event loop and callbacks or deal with "futures" and "promises" which are mere callbacks wrapped in pretty objects.

I invite you to read [this classic essay](https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/) which explains this stuff with much more beautiful words.